# Using while loop to output data of a specific id in same table row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm thinking I need to use a while loop within a while loop, but when I do I receive bizarre results.

I have the following PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.title, c.image, u.profileImage, u.fname, u.lname, u.level AS ulevel, u.city, u.state, u.hs, u.ps, uc.id, uc.cid 
        FROM c, u, uc 
        WHERE uc.cid = c.id AND uc.userid = u.id 
        ORDER BY usercollege.createdate ASC";


        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


            if ($row['status'] == null) {
                 echo "";
            }

            if ($row['ulevel'] == "A Profile") {
                 echo '<tr>' .
                     '<td class="small">' . '<a href="http://www.example.com/aprofile.php?user="'.$row["username"] . '>' . '<img src="'.$row['profileImage'].'" />' . '</a>' . '</td>' .
                     '<td class="large">' . $row['fname']. ", " . $row['lname'] . '</td>' .
                     '<td class="large">' . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . '</td>' .
                     '<td class="large">' . $row['hs'] . '</td>' .
                     '<td class="largest">' .
                          '<div class="Limage">' . '<img src="images/c/'.$row['image'].'"/>' . '</div>' . 
                     '</td>' .
                  '</tr>';
```

`$row['image']` within `<div class="Limage">` currently returns just ONE image, but the database can have up to 10 images per userid. Obviously, this loop (if there are more than one image per user) will create a new row for the user with a different image.

I am trying to achieve having all images (up to 10) appear within the same row for the same user, without replicating the same user in the table.

Comment: How many users in the DB?

Comment: Did you run the query in the terminal? if so what result did you get?

Comment: Do you want us to guess what `c`, `u` and `uc` mean? Give your tables proper names.

Comment: where is loop #2, what have you tried for that, where do the images come from?

Comment: @cale_b just a few users at the moment

Comment: @PaulSpiegel was using abbreviations for simplicity. c=colleges, u=users, uc=usercollege

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin - readability should always be first, then performance ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while your question is a bit hard to follow I can tell you what you need to do, which is not a loop within a loop ( even though it is ).  So because I don't care to decider you schema but I think I understand your issue, i'll outline it with psudo code

First you need to organize your data

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

     $users = []; //initialize variable to store data in. 

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          if( !isset( $users['u'.$row['id']]){
                $users['u'.$row['uid']] = $row; //group users by id 
           }
           $users['u'.$row['uid']]['images'][] = $row['image'];
     }
      //*note you'll have to probably add  u.id as uid to you select.

     foreach( $users as $user ){
     //... code/html for displaying user (open).
        foreach( $user['images'] as $img){
        //... code/html for displaying image.
        }//end foreach image
    //... code/html for displaying user (close).
    }//end foreach user
```

What you wind up with for the `$users` array is something like this when you output it with `var_export()` etc.

```
    [ 
       [ 'u10' => [
             'id' => 10,
             'images' => [
                  '{src for image1}',
                  '{src for image2}',
             ]

       ]
```

When you pull the records with the join you get a reflection of the one to many relationship users have to images.  So you have the same user row for each image row.  All you need to do is group them by user id, and that will make your code down stream much easier.  Unless your dealing with 1000's of users it will probably have minimal impact on the time, and is well worth it to simplify the HTML structuring.  The order they are returned in the sql could be causing all kinds of issues, you could start with user `1` have `10` other users then end with user `1`, this way they are grouped nicely in the first loop. To group them we can rely on the fact that associative keys in PHP are unique.

I add the `u{id}` there because certain PHP functions have a way of resting numeric keys, that just avoids that becoming an issue.  Most the time it's not needed, but it's precautionary and takes little effort, makes the array a bit easier to read and IMO a good habit.

Lastly if I recall correctly in CSS, an id of `id="10"` ( `#10{ ..no dice.. }` ) is not valid but one of `id="u10"` is.  A bit of an explanation on that can be found here

https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Answer (score 1):

If each row contains identical data, except avatar, You need concatenate rows in query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.image SEPARATOR ','), u.profileImage, u.fname, u.lname, u.level AS ulevel, u.city, u.state, u.hs, u.ps, uc.id, uc.cid 
        FROM c, u, uc 
        WHERE uc.cid = c.id AND uc.userid = u.id
        GROUP BY c.id
        ORDER BY MAX(usercollege.createdate) ASC
```

Then your result (image field) contains something like this:

```
avatar1.png,avatar2.png,avatar3.png,avatar4.png
```

Now You can explode sql-result and show in foreach loop.

Comment: Group Concat has a max char limit, while not necessary an issue in this question, it has a nasty habit of truncating data without telling you.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: "database can have up to 10 images per userid", so ex. sha1sum as avatar name + extension + delimiter, its about 43 characters per avatar. It's just about 430 of maximum CONCAT_GROUP (1024) characters.

Answer (score -1):

You can add order by uc.userid (and others) so in result array users will have all their raws closely. After that in your while loop u can check if userid changed - then its a new user.

Comment: The user is posting specific code, and already has some idea of what the algo should be. Its not a great question, but your answer does not go any further than his question did. Its just psuedo code, and unclear psuedo code at that. -HTH

Comment: Well, first of all, my answer was just a direction to think about, and not a complete working example.
Nested loops and storing all database query result data to array are not a good idea for performance, becouse we dont know where this code will be used. So advice with pseudo code is not that bad.